# How provide several options (not just one) after initialization?

Tags: jquery

Can several options (after init) be provided at once?

```
$('<p>Dialog</p>').dialog().parent().draggable( "option", "containment", false );
```

If I also want `scroll: false`, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeneralHenry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491845/generalhenry) informed it is...

```
draggable('option', {
    containment: false,
    scroll: false
});
```